# usage of ecc_enable_override

Tags: drivers

I found a grub parameter - ecc_enable_override

Does it mean if BIOS enabled ECC detection, enable 'ecc_enable_override' parameter will change to OS detect ECC?

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/067ba54c7a7d4cb76da4c8434bd6f117b61ac8ee/drivers/edac/amd64_edac.c#L11

```
/*
 * Set by command line parameter. If BIOS has enabled the ECC, this override is
 * cleared to prevent re-enabling the hardware by this driver.
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment is misleading. If ECC is enabled by the system firmware, the kernel will see that and the `amd64_edac` module will use it, regardless of the `ecc_enable_override` setting. If ECC isn’t enabled by the system firmware, but `ecc_enable_override` is set, the kernel will try to enable ECC itself.

The comment means that if the system firmware has enabled ECC, the kernel won’t re-enable it.